# Unhide Document Library Items Hidden by JavaScript?

Tags: document-library, hidden, pages

I have a public multilingual site which displays (among other things) products in a Document List. On the outside everything is OK, and displayed correct. On the inside (admin mode) the product pages are supposed to be displayed in a Document Library, but some countries products are hidden.

From the source of the web page I find the following script which I'm unable to locate in my solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">HideListViewRows("onetidDoclibViewTbl0");</script>
```

And my All Documents view looks like this:

[image: All Documents View]

If I make a test-view, all items are shown as expected:

[image: Test View]

My problem is - I can't find it in the solution or somewhere in the JavaScript files on the production server. Where do I find this snippet of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know where HideListViewRows is defined, but its added from the C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XML\VWSTYLES.xml file.

E.g:

```
<xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$IsDocLib or dvt_RowCount = 0"><script type='text/javascript'>HideListViewRows("onetidDoclibViewTbl0");</script></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <script type='text/javascript'><xsl:value-of select ="concat('HideListViewRows(&quot;', $List, '-', $View, '&quot;);')"/></script>
            </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Thanx for your effort, but HideListViewRows doesn't exist in the VWSTYLES.xml.

Comment: However, using @Dandroid suggestion I found the HideListViewRows in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\XSL\VWSTYLES.xsl.

Answer (score 2):

For some odd reason, the items came back after selecting Modify this View > Scroll down to the bottom of the edit view page and select OK (without making any changes).

[image: Modify View]

It exceeds my knowledge why our SharePoint instance behaves this way - but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's nested in one of the many javascript files in `layouts` folder.

You can download a software called [FileSeek](http://www.fileseek.ca/) and search through all files in this folder using keywords, in this case "function HideListViewRows".

I have no affiliation with this piece of software.